# Is there another method we can use to import local images without using usual import statement?

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to import images from different folders, but nothing is working. It seems like images can not be read, because I am able to get in the specific folder that contains images but then when trying to get the images, they are not found in the same folder

**Files structure**

[image: 1]

**Import statement**

[image: 2]

**Reference of the imported image**

[image: 3]

Comment: Can we have your folder structure and maybe a bit of code to check how you import your image?

Comment: I just did, thank you.

Comment: try with a relative import maybe import background from '../2.jpg'

Comment: Its not working. Im using materialize css framework, do you think there might be something off with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly define a rule for that in your package you will certainly have to use relative path to import your images

```
import background from './2.jpg'
```

Comment: Its not working. Im using materialize css framework, do you think there might be something off with it?

Comment: where is located the file where you have the import statement? I don't think materialize is the problem here

Comment: its in the components folder

Comment: if it's directly under components like "src/components/myfile.jsx" and your image under "src/2.jpg" import background from '../2.jpg' should work. do you have a tsconfig file or jsconfig file with a compilerOptions property?

Comment: yes I have a tsconfig file

Comment: Can i see it or maybe only the compilerOptions part?

Comment: "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"